# GStreamer. How to set videoconvert output format?

Tags: c++, video, gstreamer, rgb, multimedia

I want to read and show video from file any format, also edit video frame data, for example, drawing rects.

**OpenCV is banned**

How I image solution.
We need sequence of elements:
`filesrc -> decodebin -> videoconvert -> autovideosink`
**decodebin** decodes video data from any format to x-raw and sends to videoconvert.
**videoconvert** converts video frames from any frame format to specific format (for example, I want to **RGB**).
We can use **Pad Probe** mechanism to connect our callback where we can edit video. I want to set RGB format to **videoconvert** output and work with that format in my callback.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("videoshow");

    GstElement *filesrc = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "videofile");
    g_object_set(filesrc, "location", "video.mp4", NULL);

    GstElement *decodebin = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "decoder");
    GstElement *videoconvert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "converter");
    GstElement *videosink = gst_element_factory_make("xvimagesink", "videosink");

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), filesrc, decodebin, videoconvert, videosink, NULL);

    if (gst_element_link(filesrc, decodebin) != TRUE ||
        gst_element_link(videoconvert, videosink) != TRUE)
    {
        g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    // link decodebin and videoconvert after some time, when decodebin read file metadata
    g_signal_connect(decodebin, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(on_decodebin_ready), videoconvert);

    // setting our callback for edit video
    GstPad *vc_output = gst_element_get_static_pad(videoconvert, "src");
    gst_pad_add_probe(vc_output, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, on_pad_probe, NULL, NULL);
    gst_object_unref(vc_output);

    GstStateChangeReturn ret = gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
    {
        g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    GstBus *bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
    GstMessage *msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GstMessageType(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS));

    if (msg != NULL) {
        GError *err;
        gchar *debug_info;

        switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
            gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
            g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n",
                        GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
            g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n",
                        debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
            g_clear_error (&err);
            g_free (debug_info);
            break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
            g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
            break;
        default:
            /* We should not reach here because we only asked for ERRORs and EOS */
            g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
            break;
        }
        gst_message_unref (msg);
    }

    gst_object_unref(bus);
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);
    return 0;
}
```

```
static void on_decodebin_ready(GstElement *decodebin, GstPad *new_pad, GstElement *videoconvert)
{
    GstPad *vc_input = gst_element_get_static_pad(videoconvert, "sink");
    if (gst_pad_is_linked(vc_input))
    {
        gst_object_unref(vc_input);
        g_print ("We are already linked. Ignoring.\n");
        return;
    }

    g_print("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME(new_pad), GST_ELEMENT_NAME(decodebin));

    GstCaps *new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(new_pad);
    GstStructure *new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure(new_pad_caps, 0);
    const gchar *new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name(new_pad_struct);

    if (g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "video"))
    {
        gint w, h;
        gst_structure_get_int(new_pad_struct, "width", &w);
        gst_structure_get_int(new_pad_struct, "height", &h);

        GstPad *vc_output = gst_element_get_static_pad(videoconvert, "src");
        GstCaps *new_output_caps = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw",
                                                "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB",
                                                "width", G_TYPE_INT, w,
                                                "height", G_TYPE_INT, h, NULL);
        /* it's true but <videosink:sink> caps video/x-raw, format=(string)RGB, width=(int)640, height=(int)360 not accepted */
        bool ok = gst_pad_set_caps(vc_output, new_output_caps);
        gst_caps_unref(new_output_caps);

        GstPadLinkReturn ret = gst_pad_link(new_pad, vc_input);
        if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED(ret))
            g_print("Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", new_pad_type);
        else
            g_print("Link succeeded (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type);
    }

    gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);
    gst_object_unref(vc_input);
}

static GstPadProbeReturn on_pad_probe(GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer user_data)
{
    /* just i check video format */
    GstCaps *caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(pad);
    gchar *str = gst_caps_to_string(caps);
    g_print(str, NULL);
    g_free(str);
    gst_caps_unref(caps);

    return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}
```

**decodebin** has **I420** format.
And I awaiting **src pad** of **videoconvert** will be **RGB** format, but **on_pad_probe** prints **YV12** (why?).
Also in console I got lines:
`<videosink:sink> caps video/x-raw, format=(string)RGB, width=(int)640, height=(int)360 not accepted`
and
`<converter:src> Sticky event misordering, got 'caps' before 'stream-start'`

I just need a place where I can edit video frames. And I just can’t get the image into the format I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your videosink probably doesn't support RGB format as input. You would add a second converter for further converting RGB into a format supported by the videosink such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>


/* This callback function will be called each time the videoconverter has prepared its output frame */
static GstPadProbeReturn
cb_have_data (GstPad          *pad,
              GstPadProbeInfo *info,
              gpointer         user_data)
{
  GstMapInfo map;
  guint32 *ptr;
  GstBuffer *buffer;

  buffer = GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_BUFFER (info);
  buffer = gst_buffer_make_writable (buffer);
  /* Making a buffer writable can fail (for example if it
   * cannot be copied and is used more than once)
   */
  if (buffer == NULL) {
    g_print("Writable buffer creation failed. Aborted");
    return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
  }

  /* Mapping a buffer can fail (non-writable) */
  if (gst_buffer_map (buffer, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE)) {
    ptr = (guint32 *) map.data;

    /* Process your frame here. This example just ouputs a dot. */
    g_print(".");

    gst_buffer_unmap (buffer, &map);
  }

  GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_DATA (info) = buffer;

  return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}

gint
main (gint   argc,
      gchar *argv[])
{
  GMainLoop *loop;
  GstElement *pipeline;

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);
  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  pipeline = gst_parse_launch("filesrc location=video.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert name=conv ! video/x-raw,format=RGB ! videoconvert ! autovideosink", NULL);
  if (pipeline == NULL)
    g_error ("Failed to launch pipeline");

  GstElement *conv = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "conv");
  if (conv == NULL)
    g_error ("Failed to find conv in pipeline");
 
  GstPad *pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (conv, "src");
  gulong probe_id = gst_pad_add_probe (pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER,(GstPadProbeCallback) cb_have_data, NULL, NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pad);
  gst_object_unref (conv);

  /* run */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* wait until it's up and running or failed */
  if (gst_element_get_state (pipeline, NULL, NULL, -1) == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_error ("Failed to go into PLAYING state");
  }

  g_print ("Running ...\n");
  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  /* exit */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);

  return 0;
}
```